# Client not receiving SignalR signals inside Vue.js app

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, signalr

Hi I am practicing with SignalR. I made a simple chat app, following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-5.0). After I click the Send button, I can see the client properly sending the message to the server, which receives it and then broadcasts it to all clients. The clients does not seem to receive the message, or the event does not fire. I tried looking for solution online, but can't quite find it.

The hub code:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Message sent with content: user: {user}, message: {message}");
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

The Client Vue.js code:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
    user: "",
    message: "",
    log: [{
        user: "System",
        message: "Welcome to all chat."
    }],
    connection: null,
    buttonDisabled: true,
},
methods: {
    SendMessage: function() {
        this.connection.invoke("SendMessage", this.user, this.message).catch((err) => {
            return console.error(`Error on connection.invoke(): ${err.toString()}`);
        });
        this.message = "";
        console.log("Message sent");
    }
},
mounted: function() {
    this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/ChatHub").build(); // connecto to the hub

    this.connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) => {
        this.log.add(`${user} says ${message}`);
        console.log("Message received");
    });
    this.connection.start().then(
        () => {
            this.buttonDisabled = false;
            console.log("Connected to chat");
        }
    ).catch((err) => {
        return console.error(`Error on connection.start(): ${err.toString()}`);
    });
}
});
```

The client html:

```
<div id="app">
<div>
    <h1>All chat</h1>
</div>

<div>
    <label>
        User name:
    </label>
    <input v-model="user">
</div>

    <div>
    <label>
        Message:
    </label>
    <input v-model="message">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="Send Message" v-on:click="SendMessage" v-bind:disabled="buttonDisabled"/>
</div>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="mess in log" >
            <div>
                <h2>{{mess.user}}</h2>
                <a>{{mess.message}}</a>
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the correct way to do this is:

```
        var self = this;
        this.connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function(user, message) {
            self.log.push({ user: user, message: message });
            console.log("Message received");
        });
```

Still much to learn for me. Coming from hard-typed languages makes JS particulary hectic.